# Counting non empty values in a column, but resetting counter based on an adjacent column

Tags: excel

I'm currently trying to write a testing plan for an application with each step needing a 3-part number based on Module, Test, Test Step.
So for example the test for the third module, second test, fourth step should be 3.2.4.

Example:
[image]

Currently I have the 3 parts in separate columns, with a 4th column concatenating them together.
The module counter is no problem with `=COUNTA(INDIRECT("E18"&":E"&ROW()))` (table starts at row 18).

My problem starts with the other 2 counters, as they need to reset once the previous counter increments.
So when a new module is added, the second counter needs to reset back to 1, and likewise for the third counter (note that each module can have any number of tests, and each test can have any number of steps, so this counter needs to be dynamic and only reset to 1 when the previous counter increments by 1).

I've tried a mix of CELL("address"), LOOKUP and INDEX but none of my combinations seem to achieve what I need.

Comment: your sample data shows consistent steps of 3,  is it possible to have more or less steps than 3?

Comment: Both less and more is possible. Any number for each column.

Comment: @ForwardEd updated sample screenshot for clarity

Comment: Updated answer below

Comment: Alternatively will Module, Test, and Step always end in the digits that correspond to the count?

Comment: No they won't end in the digit, but your answer did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In column C use the following formula

```
=IF(F18="",C17,0)+1
```

Simply adds one to the previous number unless there is a new test in which case it resets to 1.  Note if row 17 is not blank, replace the formula in the first row only with 1 as a seed/starting point.

In column B use the following:

```
=IF(E18="",B17+(F18<>""),1)
```

Adds 1 only when there is a new test lable, but reset to 1 if there is a new module.  Note if row 17 is not blank, replace the formula in the first row only with 1 as a seed/starting point.

In column A use the following:

```
=COUNTA($E$18:E18)
```

Simply counts the number of module entries from the start of the range to the current row you have copied to.

And for column D:

```
=A18&"."&B18&"."&C18
```

[image: POC]

Comment: Option A will reset after 3 in both cases, right? That wouldn't work as each module can have any number of tests and each test can have any number of steps. The counters need to reset only when the previous column increments.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.